# Correct way to get nullable type from Type.GetType(string)

Tags: c#, types

How do I get the type of a nullable using `Type.GetType(string)` from a string like: `System.Boolean?` and `System.Nullable<System.Boolean>`?

Both of these are wrong and I'm not sure what's the correct way.

By wrong I mean writing `Type.GetType(X)` returns null

Comment: ``Type.GetType("System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]")``

Comment: You need the string `System.Nullable\`1[System.Boolean]`, but this sounds rather like an XY problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As documented in the [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#system-type-gettype(system-string)) of `Type.GetType(string)`:

> The name of a generic type ends with a backtick (`) followed by digits representing the number of generic type arguments. The purpose of this name mangling is to allow compilers to support generic types with the same name but with different numbers of type parameters, occurring in the same scope.

> For generic types, the type argument list is enclosed in brackets, and the type arguments are separated by commas.

Therefore, to get the `System.Type` of `bool?` from a `string`, you need to use the following:

```
Type.GetType("System.Nullable`1[System.Boolean]");
```

Where:

`System.Nullable` is the generic type name.

`` `1 `` identifies the number of generic arguments (1).

`[System.Boolean]` specifies the generic argument.

Comment: Techincally speaking, a generic type doesn't *have* to have the backtick and number, but that is the convention, and is used across the BCL and by default in C#

Comment: @Charlieface I'm not sure what you're implying here. The documentation for `Type.GetType` states that generic types must be identified with a backtick and digits, and indeed if they are omitted it results in an exception: https://dotnetfiddle.net/I9xgeZ

Comment: That exception is just because there is both `System.Nullable` and `System.Nullable<T>`, [if you try it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/F7TMM0) with another type you get a null-ref. The [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-6.0) actually states: *"All compilers that support the common language runtime will emit the simple name of a nested class, and reflection constructs a mangled name when queried, in accordance with the following conventions."* In other words it's a compiler convention, but if you manually compile the IL you can do what you want